# Embed string into .NET assembly at compile time

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I'd like to specify a value at compile time that is embedded in my assembly.  Essentially what I'd like is to define a C preprocessor definition that I could then use in my code and refer to at runtime.  I know that you can't exactly do this in .NET so I'm trying to figure out what my next best alternative would be.

Edit: To add an example to hopefully make my goal a bit more clear.  I'd like to embed some timestamps and author information into the compiled assembly.  So when I copy my executable to another machine I can tell exactly when it was built and by whom (say, in an about box).

Comment: Is that what you are looking for (embedded resources)?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

Comment: Is what you want to define a string literal?  If so, then it can be done.  C# has preprocessor directives, they just aren't as powerful as C/C++ ones; they can't define/execute functions but instead are just literals that are/are not added.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context about what you're trying to do? Perhaps a code sample of the equivalent C. While C# does have a preprocessor, it's quite limited (and with good reason I think, having seen C code full of #Defines being a bit of a nightmare to maintain in the past)

Comment: It's really not clear what you want to do. Do you need to supply the string *on the compiler command line*?

Comment: Yes, ideally I'd like to provide it on the command line as part of my nant build system.

Comment: I'd like to be able to provide a property 'BuildTimestamp'=<currenttime> and then somehow refer to BuildTimestamp in code at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly clear what you want, but maybe you need to generate something constant value based on environment/command line arguments?

One option  (which give you ability to shoot yourself in the foot with C preprocessor too): generate .CS file at build time and compile. You can easily do it in "before build" step and simply add generated file into the project.

---

Here are basic steps to generate some file at build time. Have some CMD file to create CS in project folder:

```
:-----   generate.cmd {file.Name}  - generates some CS:
echo class Generated { public const int Value=42;} >%1
```

Add to before build step (solution->properties->Build events

```
$(ProjectDir)generate.cmd $(ProjectDir)Generated.cs
```

Add "Generated.cs" (with step above it will be in project root) to you project.

Than use `Generated.Value` as needed.

---

Better implementation of this approach would be to define custom property in your project file (.csproj) and set it when you run build (see "/property:name=value" argument of [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms164311%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) ). Than either directly implement what you need in the project (you can generate files in .csproj with 
[WriteLinesToFile task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms164305%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) ) or pass the proerty to external tool.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare constant fields like so, that you then access like any other field:

```
private const string c_String = "FooFooFoo!";
```